# Interactive input, strings and quoted items

Tags: interactive

```el
(defun ecli-metadata-single (ecli meta)
  "meta needs to be quotes \n example: (case-metadata ECLI:NL:HR:2013:BY6108 'identifier)"
  (interactive "sEnter ecli: \nxEnter identifier: ")
  (insert (car (cddr (assoc  meta (ecli-metadata-full ecli)))))
 )

(ecli-metadata-single "ECLI:NL:HR:2007:BA2511" 'date)
```

What this code does is getting some metadata from a remote xml-file. The code seems to work fine when I use just type the expression, however, the interactive version does not insert the data, instead throwing an error saying

> wrong type argument: char-or-string-p, nil.

I have looked up (interactive) in `C-h f`, and tried many of the alternative characters for input. However, I still get the same (non-)result. After browsing stack-overflow and not finding a suitable answer, I 'gave up' and decided to ask this question.

To recap:

My goal is to make the above function interactively insert data. The first argument is an identifier-code, and the second argument is the data I want from the retrieved xml (other code not shown due to length). The first argument is a string `"ECLI:NL:HR:2013:BY6108"`, and the second argument is a quoted item `'date`.

A second question would be how I can remove the required quote from the input-arguments. I have tried something like `(quote meta)`, but that did not work.

Comment: Please indicate your interactions - what you type, what you see, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you invoke the command interactively, are you typing `'date` at the prompt, or just `date`?  You should be typing `date`, because the lisp object that `interactive` reads is not an eval form; that is, the symbol you type does not need to be quoted.

When you do have the result of a quote-expression and you want to retrieve the symbol, just treat it like an ordinary list.  If `a` is `(quote foo)`, then `(car (cdr a))` is the symbol `foo`.

Comment: This worked! However, this has made me quite curious why I would have to quote if I am not calling it interactively, but not the other way around. If this requires too much general knowledge to fully explain, could you instead point me into the general direction I could start learning?

Comment: `interactive` can read different formats, `x` mean read but don't eval (i.e. you get what you type) and `X` mean read and evaluate (i.e. if you type an expression, you will get the result of the expression). If you call a function the argument is evaluated. To call something without evaluating the argument you will need a lisp **macro**, which, unfortunately, is much harder to write.